# How to use case wen in db.session.query.filter_by()? Need to be optimized Python/Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

If TestDate >= '2021-01-01', filter type of `Type_One` items, if TestDate < '2021-01-01' query type of `Type_Two` items, I use below `python` and `Flask-SQLAlchemy` to realize it, but it's ugly, how to optimize below code?

```
somewords = args.get('somewords')
search = "%{}%".format(somewords)
TestDate = db.session.query(TestProject.test_date).filter(TestProject.id==id).first()

if TestDate >= '2021-01-01':
    test_code = db.session.query(TestCodeName.code). \
    distinct(TestCodeName.code, TestCodeName.type). \
    filter_by(type='Type_One'). \
    filter(or_(TestCodeName.code.contains(search))).all()
else:
    test_code = db.session.query(TestCodeName.code). \
    distinct(TestCodeName.code, TestCodeName.type). \
    filter_by(type='Type_Two'). \
    filter(or_(TestCodeName.code.contains(search))).all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the query in the first step and add a condition in another step, like this:

```
q = db.session.query(TestCodeName.code). \
    distinct(TestCodeName.code, TestCodeName.type). \
    filter(or_(TestCodeName.code.contains(search)))

if TestDate >= '2021-01-01':
    q = test_code.filter(type == 'Type_One')
else:
    q = test_code.filter(type == 'Type_Two')

test_code = q.all()
```

4 notes for you:

- I suggest that you do not mix `filter` and `filter_by`.
- `q.all()` executes the query and returns a list (or something like that). If you need to iterate over results, you just `for i in q:...`. There is no need to call `all()`.
- I suspect that you might perhaps have a wrong idea what this `filter(or_(TestCodeName.code.contains(search)))` does.
- Your distinct does not make sense to me. As you are filtering by type, so that it always has only one value (Type_One or Type_Two), then it does not make much sense to add it to the distinct clause and you only need to be distinct by TestCodeName.code, which means just adding `distinct()` is enough.

Comment: Hi, do you know how to filter the first Chinese word by its pronounce in db.session.query.filter_by()? Thanks so much for your any advice, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70373508/how-to-filter-the-first-chinese-word-by-its-pronounce-in-db-session-query-filter   @Petr Blahos